# Python 2.7, print the list output without quotes, extracting output from html

Tags: python-2.7, list, beautifulsoup

I want the output to be like Mon 5:00 PM to 12:00 AM. Remove all the single quotes and spaces in the output check: code below

```
for count in glob.glob(os.path.join("C:\\Users\\test", "*.html")):
    soup=BeautifulSoup(open(files), 'html.parser')
    hours=soup.find_all( 'table', {'class' : "table"
    [0].get_text().strip().split()
    check=[i.encode('utf-8').strip().replace("-","to" ) for i in hours]
    print check
```

Current output:

```
['Mon', '5:00', 'pm', 'to', '12:00', 'am', 'Tue', '5:00', 'pm', 'to', '12:00', 'am']
```

Comment: Currently, it prints the output as ['Mon', '5:00', 'pm', 'to', '12:00', 'am', 'Tue', '5:00', 'pm', 'to', '12:00', 'am']

Comment: ['Mon', '5:00', 'pm', 'to', '12:00', 'am', 'Tue', '5:00', 'pm', 'to', '12:00', 'am'

Answer (score 0):

If the output is consistent, you can join the output list to obtain the desired results:

```
output = ['Mon', '5:00', 'pm', 'to', '12:00', 'am', 'Tue', '5:00', 'pm', 'to', '12:00', 'am']
date_list = []

# iterate over list (assuming list is consistent - with 6 values per section
for i in range(0, len(output), 6):
    # join the values on the list and append to date list
    date_list.append(' '.join(output[i:i+6]))

#print results
print(', '.join(date_list))
```

my output:

```
Mon 5:00 pm to 12:00 am, Tue 5:00 pm to 12:00 am
```

Comment: All the output should be in a single line , Mon 5:00 pm to 12:00 am, Tue 5:00 pm to 12:00 am, so on up to sunday

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it... There's probably a much better way though.

```
check=str(check)
check=check.strip('[]')
check=check.strip("''")
check=check.replace("','","")
```